# How to politely stop a TcpListener?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, tcplistener

I have a TCP server that works Ok but now I need to stop it and all the Threads in a safe way.
As far I research Abort method is not ok

I debugged and, when the server is started and have no connections, it seems like the code halts on the line

```
Server = New TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, Port)
```

So when I call StopServer I get an error about WSACancelBlokingCall
I can't figured out how to properly stops the server.

Here's the code complete except StartTcpClient were the data is received.

```
#Region "TCP Receive variables"
    Dim TcpOpen As Boolean = False
    Private Server As TcpListener = Nothing
    Private ServerThread As Thread = Nothing
    Friend AckString As String = ""
#End Region

#Region "TCP"
    Public Sub StopServer()
        Server.Stop()
        ServerThread.Abort()
        TcpOpen = False
    End Sub
    Public Sub InitServer(ByVal Port As Integer)
        Server = New TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, Port)
        ServerThread = New Thread(AddressOf ConnectionListener)
        ServerThread.IsBackground = True
        ServerThread.Start()
        TcpOpen = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub ConnectionListener()
        Server.Start()
        While True
            Dim client As TcpClient = Server.AcceptTcpClient()
            Dim T As New Thread(AddressOf StartTcpClient)
            T.IsBackground = True
            T.Start(client)
        End While
    End Sub
#End Region
```

**Edit:**
I make some changes in the code and now seem to work like I need.

```
Public Sub StopServer()
    TcpOpen = False
    Server.Stop()
    ServerThread = Nothing
End Sub
Private Sub ConnectionListener()
    Server.Start()
    While True
        If TcpOpen Then
            If Server.Pending Then
                Dim client As TcpClient = Server.AcceptTcpClient()
                Dim T As New Thread(AddressOf StartTcpClient)
                T.IsBackground = True
                T.Start(client)
            Else
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)
            End If
        Else
            Exit While
        End If
    End While
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The connection should be closed from the client (not server).
2. The client should send an application message to server to stop processing.
3. The server should stop processing
4. The server should perform a BeginDisconnect
5. the server should send a response to client indicating that the connection can be closed
6. The client should close the connection.
7. The server when BeingDisconnect occurs should Close/Dispose Listener.

Comment: When you say "Client" are you referring to the remote side? How I stop the TcpListener if there's no connections?

Comment: Yes.  You have a Client (the master) and the Server (slave).  Servers should only perform actions when commanded by the Client.

Comment: Yes but the problem is that the method AcceptTcpClient is a blocking call and in that condition I can't stop the server. Now I'm trying with BeginAcceptTcpClient method but only works with the first connection. I think that I need to make a thread pool but I researching how to. All this is a bit confusing for me. I'm currently reading this http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?580670-RESOLVED-Closing-a-TcpListener-without-getting-WSACancelBlockingCall-exception

Comment: See webpage : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/w89fhyex(v=vs.100).aspx.  The examples are for sockets but can be replaced with any class that inherits the socket class like tcpclient or tcplistener.